# H2 data added wont refresh until disconnect

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

This is my code:

```
package logic;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Database {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./Database/Data", "Gustavo", "123456");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,NAME VARCHAR(255));");
        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'John');");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test");
        
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("id " + rs.getInt("id") + " name " + rs.getString("name"));
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I can add the data and display it and if I run the code again (commenting the CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO) it displays the data.

The problem is that when I go to the H2 console, it doesn't show anything unless I disconnect and reconnect. After I do that, it shows any changes made or data added to the database.

Is there a problem or that's how the H2 console works?

(I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, using vs code and gradle)

Edit: I solved it

The problem was in the code I was using it in embebed mode and it only allows one connection at a time. Once I changed it to server mode using:

```
String url = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Database/Data";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/" + url, "Gustavo", "123456");
```

Comment: try `conn.commit();` after the insert statement...?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't fix it. But thanks

Comment: Glad you solved it! You can move your updates from the question into a new official answer. Having an official answer will be more likely to help other people, in the future. (You can also accept your own answer, if you want to.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. I'll do it right away.

Comment: For reference, the Help Center has a note about this: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it

The problem was in the code I was using it in embebed mode and it only allows one connection at a time. I changed it to server mode using:

```
String url = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Database/Data";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/" + url, "Gustavo", "123456");
```